# Grafana timestamp macro to use with QuestDB

Tags: grafana, questdb

Grafana `$__timeFilter(timestamp)` macro generates nanosecond precision (for some reason, only on the alert queries, still trying to work out why). QuestDB accepts either epoch microseconds or ISO timestamps strings up to microsecond precision e.g. `1656490564000000` or `2022-06-29T08:16:23.123456Z`.

How can I make Grafana to generate filter compatible with QuestDB?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `$__timeFilter(timestamp)` with the following filter:

```
timestamp BETWEEN cast($__unixEpochFrom()*1000000L as timestamp) and cast($__unixEpochTo()*1000000L as timestamp)
```

Comment: Ok, that works but it looses precision

Comment: If you need microsecond precision, you should use `__unixEpochNanoFrom()` and `__unixEpochNanoTo()` macros and divide them by 1000 to get microseconds.

Comment: See this page for the list of available macros: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/#macros

Answer (score 0):

(edited) The behaviour you describe sounds weird, as according to [the Grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/) the `timeFilter` should be consistent. I checked in any case and I am observing the same behaviour.

At QuestDB you can use the [`to_timestamp`](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/date-time#to_timestamp) function to parse a timestamp with nanoseconds precision, but internally the timestamp is still with microsecond resolution, so you'd need to use the solution suggested by Andrey and skip using the built-in grafana filter here